# Transfer data from one database to another database with different schema

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-scripts

i have problem to Transfer data from one sqlserver 2008 r2 to another sql server 2012 databases with different schema, here is some different scenario,

> 1. database 1

database 1 with tables Firm and Client, these both have FirmId and ClientId primary key as int datatype,
FirmId is int datatype as reference key used in Client table.

> 2. database 2

database 2 with same tables Firm and Client, these both have FirmId and ClientId but primary key as uniqueidentifier,
FirmId is uniqueidentifier datatype as reference key used in Client table.

> 3. problem

the problem is not to copy data from 1 database table to 2 database table, but the problem is to maintain the reference key's Firm table into Client table. because there is datatype change.

i am using sql server 2008 r2 and sql server 2012

please help me to resolve / find the solution, i really appreciate your valuable time and effort. thanks

Comment: Is this a one off transfer or something that needs to run often?

Comment: its a one off transfer, basically we changed our schema old database 1 with int datatype as primarykey and new database 2 with uniqueidentifier datatype as primarykey,

Comment: uniqueidentifier is a bad idea for primary key as it will mess up the clustered index on the primary key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll take a stab at it even if I am far from an expert on SQLServer - here is a general procedure (you will have to repeat it for all tables where you have to replace INT with UID, of course...).
I will use Table A to refer to the parent (Firm, if I understand your example clearly) and Table B to refer to the child (Client, I believe).

1. Delete the relations pointing to Table A
2. Remove the identity from the id column of Table A
3. Create a new column with Uniqueidentifier on Table A
4. Generate values for the Uniqueidentifier column
5. Add the new Uniqueidentifier column in all the child tables (Table B)
6. Use the OLD id column to map your child record & update the new Uniqueidentifier value from your parent table.
7. Drop all the id columns
8. Recreate the relations

Having said that, I just want to add a warning to you: converting to UID is, according to some, [a very bad idea](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic947283-391-1.aspx). But if you really need to do that, you can script (and test) the above mentioned procedure.

Comment: This answer looks at the surface like it is going to work. I agree with you on not letting keys be uniqueidentifiers/guids.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the problem is at point 5 and 6. i have about 10k records in reference table, is there will be manually matching reference key and update key?

Comment: @adnan: no you are not supposed to do that manually, of course. When you have finished step 4 Table A will have old_id (int) and new_id (guid).
Therefore for each Table B Record you can look up the new_id value using old_id as a reference.